# angular ngAfterContentInit pass data to children compoent

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am making an http call in the ngAfterContentInit and depending upon the response , I want to pass data to my child component.And child component displays some content using that.
I used

```
public static yourString: Subject<String> = new Subject<string>();
```

in the child and subscribed to it in the child constructor. I invoked the 
`YourChildComponent.yourString.next(yourUpdatedval)` in the ngAfterContentInit ..

But the problem is that , the child constructor runs later and the subscription happen after the event is fired.How can i fix this?

I actually want to update child with the values of http call from ngAfterContentInit of parent.This is my original requirement.

Comment: Did you try using two way binding? This way once your http request is done and you change the value, the value in your child component will be updated correspondingly.

Comment: You mean using @Input?

Comment: Using only `@Input` would mean, that changing the data in your child component, wouldn't update it in the parent component. If that's your desired behaviour, then yes.
To achieve two way binding, use `@Input` and `@Output`.

Comment: I just need to update Child. But this more of a programmatical update of value in the child .So i am not sure if it will work

Comment: You could always use Eventhandling aswell. So use `@Output` in your child component and call that EventEmitter, when your child component is finished loading. In your parent component use a function, that listens to that event and starts the http call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an `@Input` property on your Child and pass the value that you want to using the property binding syntax. Something like this:

**`ChildComponent`** Class:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() childProperty;
}
```

**`ParentComponent`** HTML:

```
<app-child [childProperty]="childProperty"></app-child>
```

**`ParentComponent`** Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent  {

  childProperty = {
    foo: 'bar'
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .subscribe(user => this.childProperty = user);
  }
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2fdq6p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts) for your ref.

---

**NOTE:** You should see a very slight flip on the View as the Values have changed. But it would change without any issues.

---

### UPDATE

You can also use a `SharedService` to share data between these two components. Ideally, since there is a parent-child relationship between these two components, it doesn't make much sense. But since you've already taken that road, let's fix the issue at hand.

So your `SharedService` would look something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  private sharedData: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
  sharedData$: Observable<any> = this.sharedData.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  updateSharedData(updatedData) {
    this.sharedData.next(updatedData);
  }

}
```

You can pass some data from your `ParentComponent` by calling the `updateSharedData` on the SharedService:

```
...

import { SharedService } from './shared.service';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent  {

  ...

  anotherPropertyForChild = {
    anotherKey: 'Another Value'
  };

  constructor(
    ...,
    private shared: SharedService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.shared.updateSharedData(this.anotherPropertyForChild);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    ...

    // Something like this:
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
      .subscribe(post => this.shared.updateSharedData(post));
  }
}
```

And then in your ChildComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';

@Component({...})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  ...
  anotherChildProperty: any;

  constructor(private shared: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.shared.sharedData$.subscribe(
      sharedData => this.anotherChildProperty = sharedData
    );
  }

}
```

I've updated the Stackblitz with this implementation as well.

Hope this gets you where you want.

Comment: I tried to access the this.childProperty in the constructor of ChildComponent  ; its undefined.Why is it so?

Comment: That's because the `@Input` properties are only accessible once `ngOnChanges` runs. `ngOnChanges` would run after the constructor runs and it runs whenever there's any change in the `@Input` properties of a Component.

Comment: So which method is safe to access the childProperty

Comment: I think it should be pretty safe to be used in the `ngOnInit` as it runs after the first `ngOnChanges` and you can expect to get the property value in there.

Comment: I am not getting the value in ngOnInit as well.. I can get the value in the HTML...ngonit gets fired before my parent http call becomes successful..How to solve this?

Comment: How exactly do you plan on using this value? Are you okay if your Child Component is not rendered until you get the value from the Http Call? If your answer is yes, you can put an `*ngIf` on your ChildComponent. It won't render until the Http Call is complete and hence after that you'll be able to get that value.

Also, since `ngOnChanges` gets called every time there's a change in one of the `@Input` properties, you can write your logic there as well. **BUT IT'S VERY BAD FOR PERFORMANCE**. HENCE I won't recommend doing that.

Comment: In the child component , I get the value from parent ; make another http call and show the value.. so the value is used in the component itself.

Comment: I think it would be really helpful if you could clearly state your use case. It could have something to do with routing and child routes. Things of that sort. So please state your intent clearly so that something could be thought about solving your issue. There are n different ways to address your issue but without the actual use case, it won't be possible to suggest the best solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187954/discussion-between-jocket-and-siddajmera).